# Getting same data frame after resampling

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting the same data frame after resampling

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data['intradayCandleData'])
#df["datetime"] = df['dateTime']
df.dateTime = pd.to_datetime(df.dateTime)
df.set_index("dateTime", inplace = True) 

sample = df.between_time(start_time = '09:15:00', end_time = '15:30:00', include_end = False)

conversion = {'open' : 'first', 'high' : 'max', 'low' : 'min', 'close' : 'last', 'volume' : 'sum'}
sample.resample('5Min').agg(conversion)

print (sample)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moYiY.png)

Comment: `resample`, like most pandas operations, returns a **new** object, so unless you assign it to something it's gone. `resampled = sample.resample('5Min').agg(conversion)` then `print(resampled)` (or just assign back to `sampled` if you don't need that anymore).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Quick Trick

When you run a cell in Jupyter Notebook Cell and it displays you a result , it doesn't make any changes, so if you want to make permanent changes , **REASSIGN**

So it would be something like :

`sample = sample.resample('5Min').agg(conversion)` OR

`new_df = sample.resample('5Min').agg(conversion)`

Then changes are then saved permanently

Note : Some Methods have an inbuilt paramater, `inplace`, setting that to True does the job as well.